# app_spec that is used as AppHost for UI test_spec missing a Main Storyboard in Podspec file

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I have a development pod with the following Podspec file:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name             = 'BitLabs'
    spec.version          = '3.1.15'
    spec.summary          = 'BitLabs - monetize your app with rewarded surveys.'
    spec.description      = 'BitLabs offers the opportunity to monetize your app with rewarded surveys easily.'
    spec.homepage         = 'https://github.com/BitBurst-GmbH/bitlabs-ios-sdk'
    # s.screenshots       = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
    spec.license          = 'Commercial'
    spec.author           = { 'BitBurst GmbH' => 'bitlabs@bitburst.net' }
    spec.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/BitBurst-GmbH/bitlabs-ios-sdk.git', :tag => spec.version.to_s }
    # s.social_media_url  = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'
    
    spec.swift_version = '5.0'
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
    spec.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 5.5'
    
    spec.default_subspec = 'Core'
    
    spec.subspec 'Core' do |core|
        core.source_files = 'BitLabs/Classes/{Shared,Core}/**/*.swift'
        core.resources = ['BitLabs/Resources/{Shared,Core}/**/*.xib', 'BitLabs/Localizations/**/*.strings', 'BitLabs/Resources/{Shared,Core}/**/*.xcassets']
    end
    
    spec.subspec 'Unity' do |unity|
        unity.source_files = 'BitLabs/Classes/{Shared,Unity}/**/*.swift'
        unity.resources = ['BitLabs/Resources/Shared/**/*.xib', 'BitLabs/Localizations/**/*.strings', 'BitLabs/Resources/Shared/**/*.xcassets']
    end
    
    spec.app_spec 'AppHost' do |host|
        host.source_files = 'BitLabs/AppHost/**/*.{swift}'
        host.resources = 'BitLabs/AppHost/**/*.{xib,storyboard}'
    end
    
    spec.test_spec 'UnitTests' do |test_spec|
      test_spec.source_files = 'BitLabs/Tests/Unit\ Tests/*.swift'
      test_spec.dependency 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
    end
    
    spec.test_spec 'UITests' do |test_spec|
        test_spec.test_type = :ui
        
        test_spec.requires_app_host = true
        test_spec.app_host_name = 'BitLabs/AppHost'
        test_spec.dependency 'BitLabs/AppHost'
        
        test_spec.source_files = 'BitLabs/Tests/UI\ Tests/*.swift'
    end
end
```

If I run `pod lib lint` or `pod spec lint`, I get failure due to the UITests failing.

#### What I tried

- I want to add a UI **test_spec** to my project. And thus, I added it as shown in the Podspec file above.
- It appears that it needed an app host to run on. So, I created an **app_spec** as the AppHost.
- The app_spec had a Launcher Storyboard but not a Main one, so I created a Main Storyboard and assigned it as main manually in the **pod.xcproject** file.

#### What I expected to happen

Running the test manually works fine. So, I expected that running `pod lib lint` or `pod spec lint`
would succeed.

#### What actually resulted

Both `pod lib lint` and `pod spec lint` fail for the same reason. The UI Tests are failing because the AppHost doesn't a *Main Storyboard*

But how to assign the Main Storyboard from within the Podspec? Because I am assigning it manually in my project, but this isn't enough for the Podspec.